# Нет результатов

Tags: php, mysql

```
$online_status = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM online",$db));
print $online_status['login'];
$online_infor = mysql_query("SELECT id, nickname, avatar, level, score FROM users WHERE `login`= '".$online_status['login']."'",$db);
$online_info = mysql_fetch_array($online_infor);
$online_info_id = $online_info['id'];
```

что тута может быть не так? `$online_status['login']` выводит, но `$online_infor` почему то не выдаёт результаты

Comment: Не знаю почему не работает, но вот связи между таблицами Вы неверно сделали. Таблицы users и online должны быть связаны по userID, а не userLogin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это временно, по окончанию я буду менять дизайн и всё остальное.

```
$online_status = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM online",$db));
$online_infor = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `id`='".$online_status['u_id']."'",$db);
$online_info = mysql_fetch_array($online_infor);
$online_info_id = $online_info['id'];
```

изменил на u_id, `$online_status['u_id']` выводит.

Comment: Пару советов: убери JS с игры и сожми всю графику в игре, а то страница 160 кб вешает, а это роскошь для телефона

Comment: Большинство телефонов не тянут JS, поэтому твой спойлер не будет работать

Answer (score 1):

Таблицы должны связываться между собой по цифровому ключу, а не текстовому. Возможно у вас где то затаился пробел в поле?

Comment: Кодировка полей одинаковая?

Comment: Переделайте связку полей по ключевому идентификатору, если это не сделайте, то потом будете жалеть, поверьте моему опыту...

Comment: Я так понимаю Вы мобильную игру делаете?

Comment: А в чём смысл красть весь сюжет и дизайн у стритрейсеров? Этим Вы обрекли проект на погибель, Ваш клон ни в одну соц. сеть не возьмут